# How can I avoid the warning fom an unused parameter in PLSQ?

Tags: oracle, plsql, parameters, function

Sometimes, in PL SQL you want to add a parameter to a Package, Function or Procedure in order to prepare future functionality. For example:

```
create or replace function doGetMyAccountMoney( Type_Of_Currency IN  char := 'EUR')   return number 
is
  Result number(12,2);
begin
 Result := 10000;  
IF char <> 'EUR' THEN
   -- ERROR NOT IMPLEMENTED YET
  END IF;  
    return(Result);
end doGetMyAccountMoney;also
```

It can lead to lots of warnings  like

```
Compilation errors for FUNCTION APPUEMP_PRAC.DOGETMYACCOUNTMONEY
Error: Hint: Parameter 'Currency' is declared but never used in 'doGetMyAccountMoney'
Line: 1
```

What would be the best way to avoid those warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is controlled by the parameter PLSQL_WARNINGS, documented for 10gR2 here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams166.htm#REFRN10249

Comment: David, your answer is not bad. Usefull and not obvious. But I will like to avoid it just in a selective way. In some languages you can add some metadata to help the compiller. May be it is not posible.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't have the ability to alter the warning levels, you could just bind the parameter value to a dummy value and document that they are for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your example has several errors.  Most importantly, you would need to change "char" to "Currency" in the IF statement; which as far as I can see would avoid the warning as well.

Answer (score 1):

Disable non-severe PL/SQL warnings:

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:SEVERE';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure you have the name and the right in the correct order in that declaration?

It complains about a parameter named 'Currency', but you aren't actually using it, are you?

On the other hand, you are using something called *char*, what is that?

Or perhaps my knowledge of PL/SQL is way off, if so, leave a comment and I'll delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Warning are useful so I don't like to switch them off completely. To pacify the compiler regarding unused parameters hints on case by case basis I do something like this, using recursive "call" to itself to use the parameters:

```sql
FUNCTION test(p1 NUMBER, p2 VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  IF FALSE THEN RETURN test(p1, p2); END IF; -- this will shut up the warning

  RETURN p2;
END test;
```