# PL/SQL - Avoid Compiler warning: "value assigned, never used"

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-warnings, plsqldeveloper

As you've probably gathered, the code below isn't real - but it highlights my point.

```sql
PROCEDURE Do_Some_Dynamic_Stuff (
    sql_  IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
    cur_ INTEGER := Dbms_Sql.Open_Cursor;
    res_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
    Dbms_Sql.Parse (cur_, sql_, dbms_sql.native);
    res_ := Dbms_Sql.Execute (cur_);
    -- ...
    -- > use cursor cur_ in this code to achieve "stuff"
    -- > value `res_` never required by the program
    -- > end program successfully without errors
    -- ...
END Do_Some_Dynamic_Stuff;
```

When compiled, the above procedure will produce a compiler warning: `Hint: Value assigned to 'res_' never used`.

I know what the warning means, and it makes sense to have the issue highlighted because it can help tidy up old code when variables defined in the `DECLARE` (or `IS`) block become redundant/unused.

I have seen similar questions asked on SO, but the answers suggest toning down the Warning levels in Oracle.  The problem is that:

1. I don't always have access to do this
2. I don't *want* to switch off the warnings - as stated, I normally like to see the message since it helps maintain clean code when a genuine variable is declared and never used

The point is that in the above scenario, the `res_` variable is necessary to allow the code to compile, but is unnecessary in the context of the `PROCEDURE`.  I just want a way to suppress the message in **this instance** of the warning

Of course, one way to work around the problem is to add a pointless line of code such as:

```
Dbms_Output.Put_Line ('avoid compiler warning: ' || res_);
```

But that's hardly a very eloquent solution, and anyway it clogs up your debug output etc. etc.  So I'm just wondering if someone out there may have a pretty solution to this little bug bear.

Comment: Which tool is it? I created procedure you posted in Oracle SQL Developer, SQL*Plus and TOAD - no such message in any of them. Which database version? I tried it on 11g and 21c.

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hCN2EkCN). Please [edit] the question and include the steps necessary to replicate the issue including: what `SYSTEM`/`SESSION` settings are necessary to generate the warnings; how you are informed of the warnings; which client you are using.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/84661/1509264

Comment: It sounds like you're using PL/SQL Developer, as I've come across similar warnings before when using that. Why do you object to seeing it in this instance? Is it because you use `dbms_sql.execute` several times in your code and you never need the value returned? If so, I'd create a wrapper procedure that has a dummy line in it (e.g. `SELECT 1 INTO res_ FROM dual;`) and then just call that procedure from your code. Otherwise, why not just ignore it? Add a comment in the code that explains the issue and move on.

Comment: @Littlefoot PL/SQL Developer by Allround Automations.

Comment: @MT0 Yes, I know.  If you read my question fully it says that I've found similar questions on SO - however, those answers ae closed (or "accepted") and are insufficient to my needs.  Hence the only option I have is to post again with a clarification of what answer I am seeking.  I refer you to point 1 and 2 in my original question.

Comment: @Boneist I see that you get my issue! The reason it's annoying is that I use "F8" (execute) to validate that my code compiles. I do it several times an hour. If the code isn't clean, an error pane pops up and points me to my missing semi-colon. However, the error pane also contains warnings; it takes a moment to realise that I have no errors to process. The pane also takes up screen-space. I want to just press "F8" to validate the code and keep coding. I don't want to spend time hiding the pane again! I know it's pedantic but I wouldn't be posting if it wasn't adding pain to my day.

Comment: @Boneist Also, I'm using this function only as an example to illustrate a point.  It's all very well to say I can create a wrapper function for this particular function, but I'm hardly going to create a wrapper function for every function in the database.  Besides, a wrapper function only buries the problem a further level down.  I've already acknowledged in the question that I can use a dummy function such as `Dbms_Output.Put_Line()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using pl/sql developer, you might want to try this (excerpt from PL/SQL Developer 12.0 User’s Guide):

> To suppress a warning you can add a -- Ignore comment after the line
> that produces the hint. This works both for Oracle compilation
> warnings described in this chapter and for PL/SQL Developer hints as
> described in chapter 20.9. You can add additional text after -- Ignore
> to describe the situation

Just note that these comments are not portable to other IDE's.

Comment: Can confirm this works for my PL/SQL Developer. Just goes to show the power of RTFM! lol

Comment: @Boneist Took the words out of my mouth!

Comment: Just to add to this correct answer, I tested with the comment `-- lots of text ignore lots of text`, and it still suppressed the warning.  So it seems that the word `ignore` can be anywhere in you comment!

Comment: This will suppress all warnings as well as errors. As much as I'd like to ignore the _value never used_ hints, it's not worth the risks of ignoring everything.

Comment: @Jamie  I agree in general, but in this case 
`res_ number -- Ignore Unused because return value of dbms_sql.execute only valid for insert/update/delete`
should be safe enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another answer to this question as well.

In `Tools > Preferences > Hints > Compiler Hints`, there's an option to assign a naming convention for variables that are never used.  `Dummy` is in the list by default, but you can assign your own (I prefer `throw` for "throw-away" because I just think its more descriptive).

[image]

Now, so long as you name your variable with the prefix `throw` (like: `throw_xml_node_`), then you won't get a warning from the compiler that the variable is never used.

I discovered this after I noticed that the `-- ignore` comment (see accepted answer) isn't recognised in PL/SQL Developer version 11 and prior, and so had to find a different solution!  I actually find this to be a more elegant solution overall.